# Selenium-webdriver JS - how to wait until an element is visible

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Using [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) ([api docs here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html)), how can you wait for an element to be visible?

I have the following functions, part of a home-made set of testing helpers, and the first one works but the second one fails (eg. it times out wating for and element to be visible even if it exists - as confirmed by the first function that works - and is visible - as confirmed by all imaginable tests and inspections of the page html/css/js).

Here they are:

```
/**
 * Wait for an element to exist
 * 
 * @param  {object} locator
 * @param  {int} timeout (ms)
 * 
 * @return {Promise<element>}
 */
// !! THIS WORKS OK
exports.waitForElement = function (locator, timeout) {
  var waitTimeout = timeout || DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;

  return this.wait(until.elementLocated(locator), waitTimeout)
    .then(() => {

        return this.findElement(locator);
      });
};


/**
 * Wait for an element to exist and then wait for it to be visible
 *
 * IMPORTANT: this is probable what you want to use instead of
 *   waitForVisibleElement most of the time.
 * 
 * @param  {hash} locator
 * @param  {number} timeout
 * 
 * @return {Promise<element>}
 */
// !! THIS FAILS TO WORK AS EXPECTED
exports.waitForVisibleElement = function (locator, timeout) {
  var waitTimeout = timeout || DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;

  return this.waitForElement(locator, waitTimeout) 
    .then(el => {
      console.log('--- element found:', el);
      return this.wait(until.elementIsVisible(el), waitTimeout)

        .then(() => {
          console.log('--- element visible!');
          // this is to make sure we are returning the same kind of
          // promise as waitForElement
          return this.findElement(locator);
        });

    });
};
```

...I tested in multiple contexts, so it's no other cause of the problem then the code inside `waitForVisibleElement` but I can't seem to find any reason for why it does not work!

---

As clarification, `this` for that code ends up being the webdriver instance (the result of `new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build()`) after an `augment` method monkeypatches a given webdriver object... probably a questionable design pattern, but no the cause for my problem here :)

---

**UPDATE:** Apparently this only happens for XPath locators, like `{ xpath: '//*[contains(text(), "first name")]' }`... not that it makes any more sense now. Also, it's the same for Firefox, so it's not a weird chrome-webdriver thingy...

Answer (score 3):

It most likely is a Promise issue.
Try this instead:

```
exports.waitForElement = function (locator, timeout) {
  var timeout = timeout || DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
  return this.wait(until.elementLocated(locator), timeout);
};

exports.waitForVisibleElement = function (locator, timeout) {
  var timeout = timeout || DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
  var element = this.wait(until.elementLocated(locator), timeout);
  return this.wait(new until.WebElementCondition('for element to be visible ' + locator, function() {
    return element.isDisplayed().then(v => v ? element : null);
  }), timeout);
};
```

Usage:

```
driver.get("...");

driver.waitForElement(By.id("..."), 2000).getText().then(function(text){
  console.log(text);
});

driver.waitForVisibleElement(By.id("..."), 2000).getText().then(function(text){
  console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me structure my promise code better. But this was not the only problem. In the end the only workaround I found was to avoid *all xpath selectors* and to add special code that tests for visibility *inside the browser* with `executeScript` for the cases I was using xpath for... probably the best think to do is just to abandon all hope and throw hack after hack until things work >90% of the time... expecting selenium/webdriver to do anything in an expectable/predictable way is pointless...

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Though I never had any issue with XPath. Could you add an example or better, create a new question with a reproducible example?